# How to add a band to xarray dataset using rioxarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have two datasets, both rasters, which I would like to combine into 1 raster. This should not be difficult, but I'm having a hard time.. Both have the same extent/resolution etc. One raster has 231 bands, the other raster has 1 band. I would like to create a raster with 232 bands. Below is some information on both rasters.

I have been looking into the merge_datasets() command, but no luck yet. Any clues?

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 231, y: 1234, x: 1234)>
array([[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
...
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]]])
Coordinates:
  * y            (y) float64 39.01 39.02 39.02 39.02 ... 39.34 39.34 39.34 39.34
  * x            (x) float64 -118.8 -118.8 -118.8 ... -118.4 -118.4 -118.4
  * band         (band) int32 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 225 226 227 228 229 230 231
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    scale_factor:  1.0
    add_offset:    0.0


<xarray.DataArray (y: 1234, x: 1234)>
array([[ 2.55955   ,  2.55955   ,  2.55955   , ..., 26.846706  ,
        19.290512  , 18.555965  ],
       [ 1.511336  ,  1.193543  ,  1.511336  , ..., 20.782856  ,
        16.041739  , 21.056656  ],
       [ 1.1935476 ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., 10.154096  ,
        11.940413  , 17.73191   ],
       ...,
       [ 3.029245  ,  3.029245  ,  1.1990428 , ...,  5.2065864 ,
         3.027078  , 27.63241   ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.5156854 ,  2.2077734 , ...,  5.1539397 ,
         4.5386004 , 19.661118  ],
       [ 1.8543341 ,  0.92740995,  0.92740995, ...,  5.1539497 ,
         3.7047918 , 13.450604  ]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * y            (y) float64 39.01 39.02 39.02 39.02 ... 39.34 39.34 39.34 39.34
  * x            (x) float64 -118.8 -118.8 -118.8 ... -118.4 -118.4 -118.4
    band         int32 1
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    scale_factor:  1.0
    add_offset:    0.0
    long_name:     slope
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried and what's not working? Be sure to include the full [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) if you're getting exceptions and please describe what you're hoping to achieve a little more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to *concatenate* alond the dimension band, but the issue is your second array includes band as a (length 0) coordinate already and it conflicts with your first array.

try this combination of [`xr.concat`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html), [`da.reset_coords`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.reset_coords.html), and [`da.expand_dims`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.expand_dims.html):

```py
xr.concat(
    [
        raster_1,
        raster_2.reset_coords('band', drop=True).expand_dims(band=[232]),
    ], dim='band',
)
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm.